# SQL Server : how to write the correct query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This is my query

```
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [OtpInfoId] ASC ) AS RowNumber, 
    [OtpInfoId] , 
    [OtpStatusId]  
INTO
    #TempTable 
FROM  
    RequestOTP.Main.TbOtpStatusHistory
```

And this is part of the results:

```
RowNumber   OtpInfoId  OtpStatusId
----------------------------------
1           1          2
2           1          1
3           1          9
4           1          5
1           2          2
2           2          1
3           2          9
4           2          5
1           3          2
2           3          1
3           3          9
4           3          5
5           3          7
```

I want write a query to return what `OtpInfoId` have `OtpStatusId` with at least one state 7

In this example, the query should return this result:

```
RowNumber   OtpInfoId  OtpStatusId
----------------------------------
1           3          2
2           3          1
3           3          9
4           3          5
5           3          7
```

But I don't know how to write it.

Comment: Did not get the question. It looks like to get the result you just have to add "OtpInfoId  = 3" to a WHERE clause.

Comment: Perhaps you could edit the title of your question to be a little more specific.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a correlated subquery with a WHERE EXIST clause.

```
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [OtpInfoId] ASC ) AS RowNumber , 
    [OtpInfoId] , 
    [OtpStatusId]  
INTO #TempTable 
FROM  RequestOTP.Main.TbOtpStatusHistory osh 
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM RequestOTP.Main.TbOtpStatusHistory 
    WHERE OtpStatusId = 7 AND OtpInfoId = osh.OtpInfoId
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM RequestOTP.Main.TbOtpStatusHistory
WHERE OtpInfoId IN (
  SELECT OtpInfoId FROM RequestOTP.Main.TbOtpStatusHistory WHERE OtpStatusId = 7
)
INTO #TempTable;
```

This subquery returns all the `OtpInfoId` that have `OtpStatusId = 7`

Answer (score 0):

One method is to use an `EXISTS`.

```
SELECT *
       FROM (SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY [OtpInfoId] ASC) RowNumber,
                    [OtpInfoId],
                    [OtpStatusId]  
                    FROM  [RequestOTP].[Main].[TbOtpStatusHistory]) x
                    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
                                         FROM [RequestOTP].[Main].[TbOtpStatusHistory] y
                                         WHERE y.[OtpInfoId] =  x.[OtpInfoId]
                                               AND y.[OtpStatusId] = 7)
       INTO #TempTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach:

```
SELECT
    RowNumber,
    OtpInfoId,
    OtpStatusId
FROM
(
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [OtpInfoId] ORDER BY OtpInfoId) AS RowNumber,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN OtpStatusId = 7 THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY OtpInfoId) cnt
        [OtpInfoId], 
        [OtpStatusId]  
    FROM RequestOTP.Main.TbOtpStatusHistory
) t
WHERE cnt > 0
INTO #TempTable;
```

Note that the row numbering in your expected is not clear, because there is no obvious column which provides that ordering.  What is missing is a partition on the `OtpInfoId`, so I added one.

Answer (score 0):

Please try following script to see if it satisfies your requirement.

```js
create table RequestOTP.Main.TbOtpStatusHistory
(   
OtpInfoId  int,
OtpStatusId int
)

insert into RequestOTP.Main.TbOtpStatusHistory values
(1,2),(1,1),(1,9),(1,5),(2,2),(2,1),
(2,9),(2,5),(3,2),(3,1),(3,9),(3,5),
(3,7)

;with cte as 
(
SELECT 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by OtpInfoId  ORDER BY [OtpInfoId] ASC ) AS RowNumber, 
[OtpInfoId] , 
[OtpStatusId]  
FROM  RequestOTP.Main.TbOtpStatusHistory
)
select * from cte 
where OtpInfoId in 
(select OtpInfoId from RequestOTP.Main.TbOtpStatusHistory where OtpStatusId=7)
/*
RowNumber            OtpInfoId   OtpStatusId
-------------------- ----------- -----------
1                    3           2
2                    3           1
3                    3           9
4                    3           5
5                    3           7
*/
```

Best Regards,

Rachel